# SAPUI5 does not use the correct type for custom columns in Smart Table

Tags: sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 smart table and I used the following way for defining the custom column of type `date`.

In my oData I have two columns like this:

```
<Property Name="Datum" Type="Edm.DateTime" sap:creatable="true" sap:updatable="true" sap:deletable="true" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="Datum"/>
<Property Name="AngebotAngefragt" Type="Edm.DateTime" sap:creatable="true" sap:updatable="true" sap:deletable="true" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="AngebotAngefragt"/>
```

I defined one of them as a custom column like the following:

```
<Column visible="true">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='{"columnKey": "Datum", "leadingProperty": "Datum", "sortProperty": "Datum", "filterProperty": "Datum", "columnIndex":"3", "type": "date"}'/>
        </customData>
        <Text text="{/#Meldungen/Datum/@sap:label}"/>
</Column>
```

In the older version of UI5, with same snippet of code, it showed a calendar for the custom item in `p13n` dialog when we set the type to `date`, but now I use version `1.80` and it shows an input box instead.

Here is what it shows for the the `Datum` column:

[image]

And here is what it shows for `AngebotAngefragt` column that I haven't defined as a custom column:

[image]

Comment: Related [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63260845/how-can-i-use-typeinstance-instead-of-type-in-p13n-dialog)

Comment: Reported to UI5 via this [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2970#issuecomment-669071182)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by this syntax:

```
<Column visible="true">
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData key="p13nData" value='\{"columnKey": "Datum", "leadingProperty": "Datum", "sortProperty": "Datum", "filterProperty": "Datum", "columnIndex":"3", "type": "date"}'/>
        </customData>
        <Text text="{/#Meldungen/Datum/@sap:label}"/>
</Column>
```

What really does the trick here, is the leading backslash in property value.

Without giving the backslash at the beginning in the Columns customData Definition (on js level) there will be a property type added, but with value undefined. Should have something to do with the internal handling of SAPUI5 (and the String not being escaped), but however this is not explicitly documented.

Code Example:
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/bed8274140d04fc0b9bcb2db42d8bac2 (FAQ -> 1. Example Snippet)