# How can I use typeInstance instead of type in p13n dialog?

Tags: sapui5

I already asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248828/sapui5-does-not-use-the-correct-type-for-custom-columns-in-smart-table) regarding ignoring of type of a custom column by smart table in new version of SAPUI5.

In the work around I discovered in the [API](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.P13nItem%23controlProperties) that I can use a new property called `typeInstance` instead of `type`:

[image]

Now the question is how can I pass a `typeInstance` object instead of `type` in smart table xml definition:

```
<Column visible="true">
    <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="p13nData" 
            value='{
                "columnKey": "Datum", 
                "leadingProperty": "Datum", 
                "sortProperty": "Datum", 
                "filterProperty": "Datum", 
                "columnIndex":"3", 
                "type": "date", 
                "typeInstance": {???} 
            }'/>
        </customData>
    <Text text="{/#Meldungen/Datum/@sap:label}"/>
</Column>
```

What do I have to write instead of `???`?

I discovered the `typeInstance` must represent the [`sap.ui.model.type.Date`](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.model.type.Date) based on the code that I extracted from `P13nConditionPanel.js` in SAPUI5 library:

[image]

Also when I define it like this:

```
<Column visible="true">
    <customData>
        <core:CustomData key="p13nData"
            value='{
                "columnKey": "Datum", 
                "leadingProperty": "Datum", 
                "sortProperty": "Datum", 
                "filterProperty": "Datum", 
                "columnIndex":"3", 
                "type": "numeric", 
                "typeInstance": {
                    "type":"sap.ui.model.type.Date"
                } 
           }'/>
    </customData>
    <Text text="{/#Meldungen/Datum/@sap:label}"/>
</Column>
```

Then it will take the value from `typeInstance` and ignore the `type` property:

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://ui5.sap.com/test-resources/sap/m/qunit/P13nConditionPanel.qunit.js) is some example that how can we make it in JS! But I need a way that represent same structure in XML view!

Comment: Reported to UI5 via this [issue](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2970#issuecomment-669071182)